# Debug->Exceptions option missing in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want my code to break on exceptions and so usually in VS2010 I go to the dialog Debug->Exceptions... to enable this.

But on a new install of VS2010 Professional that option in the Debug menu is completely missing.  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: This might be a profile settings issue. Could [this](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/KeithC/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=16) be the case?

Comment: This did it eran.  Please add this as an answer so that I can accept it.  Good find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio can be used with various languages and environments. Therefore, the basic IDE have different settings for each purpose (this is somewhat like Eclipse perspectives). Using a certain language profile does not mean VS cannot be used to develop another language, but some of the IDE's functionality might not be available. To solve this issue, the IDE's profile can be modified as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1z20s6z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

[image]From here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx#addexceptionscommand

Do this:

## To add the Exceptions command to the Debug menu

- On the Tools menu, click Customize.
- The Customize dialog box appears.
- Click the Commands tab and, in the Menu bar list, click Debug.
- Click Add Command.
- In Categories in the Add Command dialog box, click Debug.
- In Commands, click Exceptions and then click OK.
- (Optional) You can click Move Down to adjust the position of the Exceptions command on the Debug menu.
- Click Close.