# Stop debugger on current line of code being executed in Visual C# Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, infinite-loop, visual-studio-debugging, break

So my program seems to be stuck in a loop somewhere. Unfortunately it doesn't run out of memory or overflow the stack, so it just keeps running. To figure out what it's doing I could of course start putting in break points at random places in the code, but I'm hoping there's a more efficient way of doing it.

I would like to simply stop the debugger at the line of code that is currently being executed, but I can't find a command for this in VS. I've searched for how to do it and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214355/stop-debugger-on-current-line-of-code-being-executed), but it seems this was a feature in VS 2008 and not in 2010!?

Does anybody know how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're right that you're looking for the pause button (command 'Break All' in 'Debug' category), which is a feature of VS2010. If you can't see it, it might be IDE profile issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053028/debug-exceptions-option-missing-in-vs2010), or if you're on VS2010 express [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530579/visual-c-2010-express-does-not-have-break-all).